# Why should I use startActivity in a Service

Tags: android, service, android-activity

Why should I use `startActivity()` in a Service? If I need an Activity a have to call an activity and if I need a "delayed activity" I have to use the notification. So, why should I use `startActivity()`?

Answer (score 1):

> why should I use startActivity() in a
>   Service?

Generally, you should not use `startActivity()` from a `Service`.